# некорректное получение значение переменной session flask javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, flask, jinja2

Отправляю POST-запрос из шаблона следующим образом:

```
{% block test_block %}
    console.log('FROM test_block ');
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            'service_name':'{{ session['servicename'] }}',
            'master_name': '{{ session['mastername'] }}'
        },
        url: '{{url_for('main.main_get_allow_dates')}}',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false
    }).done(function(){
        console.log('ajax post done!');
        var a = '{{ session['allow_dates'] | safe }}';
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log('ajax post fail!');
    });

{% endblock %}
```

На сервере происходит по этому POST-запросу некоторая работа, после которой в `session['allow_dates']` записывается словарь.

После этого (по идее) в секции `.done(...)` AJAX-функции должно в консоль вывестись сообщение `ajax post done!`, а в переменной `a` оказаться значение словаря, полученного при работе функции на сервере.

Заполнение этой переменной гарантируется тем, что запрос отправляется синхронный (`async: false`) (хотя тут я не уверен). Вот что происходит при запуске:

```
<script>

        $(document).bind('ready',function(){
            console.log('from base ready');




    console.log('FROM test_block ');
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            'service_name':'service_1',
            'master_name': 'dima'
        },
        url: '/main_get_allow_dates',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false
    }).done(function(){
        console.log('ajax post done!');
       var a = '';
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log('ajax post fail!');
    });


        })

        ;

    </script>
```

Как видно из полученного "выхлопа", переменные `service_name` и `master_name` корректно заполняются из переменной `session`, в консоли действительно появляется `ajax post done!`, однако в переменной `a` просто пустая строка, хотя там действительно должен появиться словарь (проверял на стороне сервера по таким же входным данным).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём тут проблема?

Comment: Вам нужно осознать что js и python выполняются в разное время и в разном месте. http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js при чтении мысленно заменять php на flask/python

Comment: @AlexeyTen, подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно подробнее почитать про скорости выполнения (но именно в контексте Flask)?

Comment: Тут вопрос не в скорости, а в фундаментальном понимании как работает протокол http и схема взаимодействия клиент-сервер

Answer (score 1):

Вы говорите:

> На сервере происходит по этому POST-запросу некоторая работа, после
>   которой в session['allow_dates'] записывается словарь.

Но пишете в переменную 'a' значение до запроса, в момент выдачи блока на страницу. Вам переменную 'a' нужно получать из js в методе `.success( data ){ let a = data }`, а не шаблонизатором:

```
{% block test_block %}
    console.log('FROM test_block ');
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            'service_name':'{{ session['servicename'] }}',
            'master_name': '{{ session['mastername'] }}'
        },
        url: '{{url_for('main.main_get_allow_dates')}}',
        type: 'POST'
    }).success(function( data ){
        console.log('ajax post done!');
        var a = data;
    }).error(function(){
        console.log('ajax post fail!');
    });

{% endblock %}
```

И

> "Заполнение этой переменной гарантируется тем, что запрос отправляется
>   синхронный"

не гарантируется, потому что в момент выдачи шаблонизатором кода страницы, запроса не происходит, потому что браузер запускает запрос позже.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Насчёт `.succes` почему-то из головы вылетело, думал, что тут достаточно `.done`.  Подскажите, если не сложно, где можно почитать про скорость выполнения запросов flask и javascript (в контексте моего вопроса)?